# Adjust width of UILabel based on its contents

Tags: ios, uilabel

I had a look on SO before asking this question. All the questions are about adjusting the height of a `UILabel` and not its width. I tried alternative methods but it did not work such as `[label sizeToFit];`. Is it possible to adjust the width of a label based on its text? I create my label in a `UITableViewCell` in story board. I want to be able to adjust its width based on the text that it is assigned. I dont want to resize the font size.

I set the text of the label in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Examples would be great please.

Thanks in advance :)

Update 1: I have a custom cell that I am making in Storyboard so not programmatically. I set the contents of each cell in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, for example, `myLabel.text = recipe.name`. The name label is quite small, however I would like to extend its width based on the length of the text, not truncate the tail or shrink the size of the text.

Update2: I have a lot of other UIElements in the cell. So I have a label in the top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, and a picture in the middle, there default is 120 because they have a background color. I set it small the there is not a huge amount of empty space in the label.

Comment: `[label sizeToFit];` not work, maybe cause of **autolayout** . So try to uncheck it.

Comment: @lee but I am intentionally using autolayout as I am targeting iPhone 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the size of the string:

```
  //Replace FLT_MAX with the maximum height/width you want the label to be, if no maximum leave as FLT_MAX.
CGSize stringSize = [YOUR_STRING sizeWithFont:YOUR_FONT constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Then size your label:

```
[YOUR_LABEL setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, stringSize.width, stringSize.height)];
```

In iOS 7 sizeWithFont is deprecated, use `boundingRectWithSize` instead:

```
NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:YOUR_LABELS_FONT
                                                                 forKey: NSFontAttributeName];

CGSize stringSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)
                                             options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
                                                     NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;
```

Comment: Which ever font you are using ... If you aren't setting it you can use [YOUR_LABEL font]; to get the current font.

Comment: If you are correctly using auto layout, you shouldn't need to do this. You may just need to set the height of your tableViewCell using this method.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work either, I do not doubt your answer, i will revise my code and get back asap

Comment: Perhaps post a screenshot of what it is doing so we can understand what it is you want. As this solution will solve your question.

Comment: The label is 120 wide at default which suits most content, but with this exceeds 15+ characters the label is still 120. The answers here did not adjust the width (120).

Comment: Why is it set to 120 ?

Comment: Apologies that would have made it clearer, I have a lot of other UIElements in the cell. So I have a label in the top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, and a picture in the middle, there default is 120 because they have a background color. I set it small the there is not a huge amount of empty space in the label.

Comment: oh ok. So what length does the stringSize give you when you give it the text that doesn't fit ? is the right text ? have you set the font/size properly?

Comment: All font sizes are set in the Attribute Inspector. The text is 16 characters when it doesnt fit

Comment: Yes but what size does  stringSize return ?

Comment: The return is: `Height = "17.7";
    Width = "98.925";`, the original is infact 50 not 120

Comment: OK. SO based on the text size/font the labels width now needs to be 98.925 in order to fit the text ....

Comment: I selected yout answer as correct as you were one of the first, it must be an issue with my code that it is not resizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(250, CGFLOAT_MAX); //250 is max desired width
CGSize textSize = [Label.text sizeWithFont:Label.font constrainedToSize:maxSize];
Label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width, 15); // desired Bounds
```

Using above code you can get frame size for perticular text, & then resize label accordingly

Comment: Unfortunately sizeWithFont is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set explicit width for UILabel. UILabel provides intrinsic content size when used with autolayout. If you add constraints that provide the label's x,y position(Top Space constraint + Leading Space constraint), autolayout will be able to determine its width height based on the content.

Comment: I dont set the constraints for the elements in the cell, but for the tableview

Comment: Why don't you start adding constraint in you cell? Since you are already using it, seems more consistent.